# Passing 2 types of array variables in codeigniter view files

Tags: codeigniter

If i have $data[] array and $another_data[] in controller how do we pass both type of data in view files ? provided that codeigniter implementation is like $this->load->view('view_page', $data)

Answer (score 9):

If you can guarantee that the array keys are unique across the two arrays you can use array_merge to merge the two arrays before passing to the view.

```
$this->load->view('view_page', array_merge($data, $another_data));
```

Otherwise you can create a parent array and store both as subarrays.

```
$parent_data = array('data' => $data, 'another_data' => $another_data);
$this->load->view('view_page', $parent_data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$data['array1'] = $array1;
$data['array2'] = $array2;
this->load->view('view_page', $data);
```

Then in your view, access the two arrays as `$array1` and `$array2`.

Comment: You can pass as many arrays as you want in the view using this method.. I always use this to pass many arrays in the view.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign them as child arrays of the array you are passing to the view. I always create a `$view_data` array in the controller, and then despatch this to the view using `$this->load->view('layout', $view_data);`

Here is some example of what I mean:

```
$view_data['page_title'] = 'Array Examples';
$view_data['view_file'] = 'examples/array';
$view_data['array_one'] = array('apples', 'bananas', 'pears');
$view_data['array_two'] = array('ford', 'skoda', 'peugeot');
$this->load->view('layout', $view_data);
```

Then in the view you can access them like the following:

```
<h6>List of fruits:</h6>
<pre><?php print_r($array_one); ?></pre>

<h6>List of cars:</h6>
<pre><?php print_r($array_two); ?></pre>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->view("first"=>demo, "second"=>demo2);

foreach( $first->array_result()  as $result )
{
    $result['test'];
}

foreach( $second->array_result()  as $result )
{
    $result['test'];
}
```