# Passing multiple query results to view

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am setting a web blog using Codeigniter.

In the view, I have 2 templates, one is for blog (2 column for sidebar) and the other one for 1 column pages. 
When I click to view a single post, the controller loads the template as follows

`$this->template->load('blog_template', 'blog_post', $data);`

Because the result of query only holds post of a called id, the sidebar that is supposed to populate all post titles, only displays the title of this very post.

To make the sidebar display all post titles, I did the following to return two query results.

```
function view_post() {
    $data = array();

    $q1 = $this->site_model->get_by_id();

    if (isset($q1)) {
        $data['by_id'] = $q1;
    }

    $q2 = $this->site_model->get_all();

    if (isset($q2)) {
        $data['records'] = $q2;
    }

    $this->template->load('blog_template', 'blog_post', $data);
}
```

And in the view, I loop through passed `$data` as in `$records as row` for sidebar and `$by_id as row` for the single post but doing this gives me `page not found` error.

I guess I shouldn't really handle more than one query results from within the same function.

How can I get what I want with a better practice?

I am using this [custom template library](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/an-introduction-to-views-templating-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: `blog_template` and `blog_post` view at same page right? `blog_template` is sidebars and `blog_post` is content area?

Comment: @Bora Yes, you are right. It's not a default Codeigniter view setup. There is `$body` inside `blog_template` that takes `blog_post`.

Comment: So you can use as `<?php $this->load->view('blog_template'); ?>` and `<?php $this->load->view('blog_post'); ?>` in your `blog_index` view file. At first set default view in controller with data `$this->template->load('blog_index', $data);`

Comment: @SeongLee Bora you're putting your template in a wrong way. Follow Bora's suggestion. 1st param = template , 2nd param = data

Comment: `Passing multiple query results` to a `view` has nothing to do with `404 error`. first make sure `$this->template->load('blog_template', 'blog_post', $data);` works by any `$data`.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña As I mentioned, I am not using the default Codeigniter template setup. [Custom Template](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/an-introduction-to-views-templating-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: @HashemQolami Can you please elaborate more on your point? The way I load my template works with `$data` except for the instance where `$data` holds multiple query results.

Comment: You may get help from this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133778/pass-two-query-result-to-view-in-codeigniter

Comment: @SeongLee I read whole of that article twice, and I'm pretty sure that the `Template` library doesn't restrict the passing `$data` to views. So, post your `blog_post` view file (and `blog_template` if needed) please, and it would be greate to know what do `get_by_id()` or `get_all()` methods return **in any cases**.